# Не могу загрузить репозиторий с гитхаба через composer(yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, git, github, composer

Вот composer.json виджета с гитхаба

```
{
"name": "vkolya/pollANDcharts",
"description": "An widget to create polls and to wrap google chart for Yii Framework 2",
"keywords": ["yii2", "poll", "widget", "poll-widget", "yii2-poll-widget"],
"type": "yii2-extension",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"license": "BSD-2-Clause",
"support": {
    "source": "https://github.com/Vkolya/pollANDcharts"
},
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Mykola Vantukh",
        "email": "vkolia@mail.ua"
    }
],
"require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "vkolya\\pollANDcharts\\": "" }
}
```

}

вот composer.json с локального сервера

```
{
"name": "nenad/yii2-advanced-template",
"description": "Improved Yii 2 Advanced Application Template By Nenad Zivkovic",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "improved", "application template", "nenad"],
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "tutorial": "http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=6",
    "source": "https://github.com/nenad-zivkovic/yii2-advanced-template"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "nenad/yii2-password-strength": "*",
    "mihaildev/yii2-ckeditor": "*",
    "codeception/codeception": "2.0.*",
    "codeception/specify": "*",
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.5",
     "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*",
    "bower-asset/push.js": "^0.0.11",
    "nlac/nlsclientscript": "dev-master",
    "pollext/poll":"dev-master",
    "scotthuangzl/yii2-google-chart": "dev-master",
    "vkolya/pollANDcharts":"dev-master"

},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
    "codeception/verify": "*",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*",
    "ext-xsl": "*"
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "_protected/vendor",
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "_protected/vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "_protected/vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}
Вроде как все верно, но composer выдает ошибку

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 Problem 1
 - The requested package vkolya/pollandcharts could not be found in any     version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так

Comment: попробуйте указать репазиторий https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. не вижу вашего пакета на packagist.org
2. не вижу секции `"repositories"` в вашем `composer.json`
3. ... других вариантов тоже не видать

подробнее почитать про подключение пакета, например, напрямую с github можно тут: [Satis: Создайте свой собственный репозиторий Composer](http://phpprofi.ru/blogs/post/25)

должно быть что-то вроде:

```
{
    ...
    "repositories" : [
        {"type" : "vcs", "url" : "https://github.com/Vkolya/pollANDcharts"}
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо тебе большое . я знал , что должен быть сервис для хранения этих пакетов